# What are the requirements to install Windows Phone Developer Tool?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I can't find it.
By requirements, I mean like:
Windows 7
Visual Studio 2010...

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Visual Studio 2010/2012 Express for Windows Phone

Windows Phone Emulator

Windows Phone SDK 7.1 Assemblies

Silverlight 4 SDK and DRT

Windows Phone SDK 7.1 Extensions for XNA Game Studio 4.0

Microsoft Expression Blend SDK for Windows Phone 7

Microsoft Expression Blend SDK for Windows Phone OS 7.1

WCF Data Services Client for Window Phone

Microsoft Advertising SDK for Windows Phone